# Not allowed to load local resources ASP NET MVC

Tags: leaflet, asp.net

```
var wmts = L.tileLayer('E:/Mapnik/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
wmts: true,
    });
    wmts.addTo(map);
```

I am trying to load the map with asp.net mvc, but I get this error. (Not allowed to load local resources ) what could be my fault ?

---

I tried but it gives the same error

Answer (score 0):

`E:` is local to your computer, so nobody but you would be able to access the resource. Instead, put the server/resource URL (which could be pointing to `localhost`)

You may consider using `file:///E:/...` but again only you would be able to access the tiles.